# Reason Visual Studio would be slower on 64-bit dual core machine?

Tags: performance

Scenario: Visual Studio 2008 (version 9) is installed on two machines:

- a desktop machine: 512 MB RAM, 1.4 GHz CPU, Windows XP (Service Pack unknown).
- a new laptop 4 GB RAM, dual 2.1 GHz CPU, 64-bit CPU, Windows 7.

While running a web project, loading/debugging and then navigating to page takes approx. < 1 second. 
On the laptop machine, the same actions take more than 3 seconds (sometimes ~ 2.8 seconds).

Question: What might cause the compilation and loading of the same VS project to be slower on the new machine? Are there settings I can tweak to make it more suitable for my computer?

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055528/is-development-programming-on-windows-7-slow.

-edit- i notice the answer link isnt valid. The problem had to do with ip6 and setting network.dns.disableIPv6 on firefox to true

Comment: Do you possibly have something else running on the new computer that could be slowing it down?

Comment: @joe, no its a fresh install, it has very few programs installed and they are ALL on my desktop as well.

Comment: Is the laptop plugged in at the time? Laptop performance is traded off for battery life when running on the battery.

Answer (score 6):

I'd look at the speed of the hard-drives as the possible limiting factor. Most laptops have 5200 RPM drives, a 7400 RPM drive can easily outperform it.

Comment: the HD speed is the same as the desktop.

Comment: Is that HD rotation rate, or actual throughput? Laptop I/O subsystems are generally slower than desktop I/O subsystems.

Comment: Seriously, unless you run a crazy company like mine... it is NOT. Laptop discs ARE SLOWER. They are made to handle harder movements etc., and use lower power - but at the price of lower IO speed. And I run such a crazy company. Heck, I boot some servers from laptop drives ;) But normally, desktop drives are QUITE faster.

Answer (score 1):

Please see Visual Studio Optimizations

Answer (score 0):

how about browser differences and/or network latency ?  Internet Explorer 7/8 ie hit's a few URL's when it first loads.  What version of ie is running on XP?

Is the laptop running on wifi, whilst the desktop is wired?

Are both computers on the same network?